# Value error with numpy arrays (shapes)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, valueerror

I keep getting a ValueError when working with numpy arrays and I can't figure out what's causing it, as it seems to be working correctly outside of my for loop. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def x(t, x_0, w):
    return x_0*np.cos(w*t)
def x_prime(t, x_0, w):
    return -x_0*w*np.sin(w*t)

w = 1
x_0 = 1
h = 0.001
t = np.arange(0, 10, h)
y = np.array([[0, 0]]*len(t))

y[0] = [x_0, 0]
# The line below works correctly, but not inside my loop
print np.array([x_prime(1, x_0, w), -w**2 * x(1, x_0, w)])*h + y[0]
for i in range(1, len(t)):
    # Euler's method
    y[i] = y[i-1] + np.array([x_prime(t, x_0, w), -w**2 * x(t, x_0, w)]) * h
```

From the `print` line I get this output: `[ 9.99158529e-01 -5.40302306e-04]`, so that seems to be working correctly. However, I'm getting this error at the `y[i]` line:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,10000)
```

I'm not sure why, since my print statement earlier is basically doing the same thing, and `y[i]` should be the same shape. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `print` line the first argument of `x()`/`x_prime()` is a scalar (`1`).

In the `y[i]` line you pass `t` instead, which is a 10000-elements array, resulting in `np.array([x_prime(t, x_0, w), -w**2 * x(t, x_0, w)])` being a (2,10000) matrix, hence the `ValueError`.

Perhaps what you want to do is:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] + np.array([x_prime(t[i], x_0, w), -w**2 * x(t[i], x_0, w)]) * h
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your algorithm try to realize, but your seems to use all the t in one iteration, maybe my change can help you.
    import numpy as np

```
def x(t, x_0, w):
    return x_0*np.cos(w*t)
def x_prime(t, x_0, w):
    return -x_0*w*np.sin(w*t)

w = 1
x_0 = 1
h = 0.001
t = range(0, int(10/h))
y = np.array([[0, 0]]*len(t))

y[0,0] = x_0
y[0,1] = 0
# The line below works correctly, but not inside my loop
print(np.array([x_prime(1, x_0, w), -w**2 * x(1, x_0, w)])*h + y[0])
for i in range(1, len(t)):
    # Euler's method
    y[i] = y[i-1] + np.array([x_prime(t[i]*h, x_0, w), -w**2 * x(t[i]*h, x_0, w)]) * h
```

Comment: because i use range instead of np.arange, look carefully for the defintion, the range is (0~int(10/h)).